# MPI 4 total processes killed (some possibly by mpirun during cleanup)

Tags: c, openmpi

I am developing the nBody simulation with C and MPI and I deploy it on AWS EC2 cluster.
I've create a bash script to run my strong scaling test case on cluster this it

```
  #!/bin/bash

 mpirun -np 1 --hostfile hostfile.txt main2 50000 20 >> test50kX20np1.txt
echo "Test 1 Terminato"
 mpirun -np 2 --hostfile hostfile.txt main2 50000 20 >> test50kX20np2.txt
echo "Test 2 terminato"
 mpirun -np 4 --hostfile hostfile.txt main2 50000 20 >> test50kX20np4.txt
echo "Test 4 terminato"
 mpirun -np 6 --hostfile hostfile.txt main2 50000 20 >> test50kX20np6.txt
echo "Test 6 terminato"
 mpirun -np 8 --hostfile hostfile.txt main2 50000 20 >> test50kX20np8.txt
echo "Test 8 terminato"
mpirun -np 10 --hostfile hostfile.txt main2 50000 20 >> test50kX20np10.txt
echo "Test 10 terminato"
 mpirun -np 12 --hostfile hostfile.txt main2 50000 20 >> test50kX20np12.txt
echo "Test 12 terminato"
 mpirun -np 14 --hostfile hostfile.txt main2 50000 20 >> test50kX20np14.txt
echo "Test 14 terminato"
 mpirun -np 16 --hostfile hostfile.txt main2 50000 20 >> test50kX20np16.txt
echo "Test 16 terminato"
```

At the end of the script the generated txt:

1. test50kX20np2.txt,
2. test50kX20np4.txt,
3. test50kX20np6.txt,
4. test50kX20np8.txt,
5. test50kX20np10.txt,
6. test50kX20np12.txt,
7. test50kX20np14.txt,
8. test50kX20np16.txt

They have this line: (for example in **test50kX20np4.txt**)

```
4 total processes killed (some possibly by mpirun during cleanup)
```

What may be due to this error?

Comment: Have you tried running a serial version? To me this looks like it's a problem in your program. There should be log files generated by the cluster with error messages, look into those. Running it with a debugger and/or valgrind would also be informative.

Comment: First, run `dmesg` and double check no MPI task was killed by the OOM killer.