# Reading doubles on a binary file with MPI

Tags: c, file, binary, mpi

I need to read a list of numbers from a binary document. I made this code but it doesn't work correctly.
The code is:

```
   MPI_File file;
   double num;
   int status;
   MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, in_file, MPI_MODE_RDONLY, MPI_INFO_NULL, &file);
   MPI_File_read_at(file, 0, &num, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, &status);
   printf("%f\n", num);
   MPI_File_close(&file);
```

What's wrong? Thanks!

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?  You should check return values and perhaps `status` to see if you have any information as to the failure.

Comment: The status is 0 in every iteration, but at the end of the code a line with the message "2 total processes killed (some possibly by mpirun during cleanup)" appears. After that, the code stops after 2 iterations. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50679564/mpi-4-total-processes-killed-some-possibly-by-mpirun-during-cleanup

Comment: I don't know the MPI API, but a quick look at the docs suggests that there is a [MPI_Finalize](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/current/man3/MPI_Finalize.3.php) call, that might properly close down the environment before exit.

Comment: Try setting a file view with `MPI_DOUBLE`. If you are running on a little endian system, manually double check the data was also written in little endian, otherwise you need to set the `external32` data representation.

Comment: I changed the file view and it's still doesn't working. Actually I'm working with a Cluster that it's all defined. Thanks!

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: "the code stops after 2 iterations." There are no iterations in your posted sample.